# How can I get a string from a 2d character array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

The 2d array:

```
char c[4][3]={{'a','b','c'},{'d','e','f'},{'g','h','i'},{'j','k','l'}};
```

As I wanted to get 'def' after running the program, I tried this code:

```
printf("%s\n",c[1]);
```

However, the result was 'defghijkl\262'. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Null terminator.

Comment: %s means a string.  You have no null terminator so it runs away on you.  A 2D array of characters is not a string.  Read about `printf`.  Learn C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print `def` in two ways:

```
char c[4][4]={{'a','b','c','\0'},{'d','e','f','\0'},{'g','h','i','\0'},{'j','k','l','\0'}};        
printf("%s\n",c[1]);
```

So, basically `printf` needs null termination to know where to stop printing

or you can print using a loop without null termination like:

```
char c[4][3]={{'a','b','c'},{'d','e','f'},{'g','h','i'},{'j','k','l'}};
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   printf("%c", c[1][i]);
}
```